# How to fix "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" when making Virtual Environments

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenv-commands

Whenever I try to use the 'virtualenv VirtualEnvironmentName' command or the 'virtualenv -p python3.8 VirtualEnvironmentName' command it says "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory." I just want to make Virtual Environments, but I always get that error saying "No such file or directory."
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To create a virtual environment, you must specify a path.

Then you can activate the python environment by running the following command:

```
your_working_directory\\Scripts\\activate
```

Most likely, the problem is that you're using a relative path for the directory.

Let me clarify how Python finds files:

> An absolute path is a path that starts with your computer's root
>   directory, for example 'C:\Python\scripts..' if you're on Windows.
>
> A relative path is a path that does not start with your computer's root
>    directory, and is instead relative to something called the working
>    directory. You can view Python's current working directory by calling
>    os.getcwd().

Other common mistakes that could cause a "file or directory not found" error include:

- You may be using escape sequences in a file path:

  ```
      path = 'C:\Users\apps'

      Incorrect! The '\n' in 'Users\apps' is a line break character!
  ```

To avoid making this mistake, you can use any one of the below methods:

- use raw string literals

  ```
     path = r'C:\Users\apps'
  ```
- you can always use this:

  ```
   'C:/Users/apps'
  ```
- another possibility is:

  ```
  'C:\\Users\\apps
  ```

Answer (score 0):

if it keeps answering something like this

[image: [Errno 2] No such file or directory]

Try to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda, but now checking the box below

[image: Path Anaconda]

Answer (score 0):

When creating the virtual environment, I was getting a error similar error.

I resolved it by removing anaconda from the PATH, and then adding the actual python dir.