# Error with creating virtualenv on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, virtualenv

When i try to run `virtualenv env` on cmd at the folder desired I get this error: `virtualenv env FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\zac\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\Lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe'`

Comment: You are probably in the wrong working directory where your virtual env is stored

Comment: i shouldnt just choose any directory to create an virtualenv?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62034948/how-to-fix-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-when-making-virtual-en